# Blank screen after installing kde desktop environment, can only login from console tty2

Tags: boot, login, kde

I wanted to put KDE plasma on my Ubuntu 20.04.

It did not work - a blank screen came up then I had to use <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>F2</kbd> to log in and then command line shows up instead of giving me the direct login access.

In order to get access to the GUI I need to type `sudo systemctl restart gdm`

I do not want to have to use tty2 console to login.

Thank you

[image: filesystem check screen that sometimes displays during boot]
[image: CLI login]

Comment: I have the same issue, but on Kubuntu 22.04. Maybe these work for you also? Can you verify which work? https://userbase.kde.org/Troubleshooting/Black_Screen